# How to divide a wxPanel horizontally?

Tags: perl, layout, wxwidgets, wxperl

I'm building a layout for a console app and [here's](http://postimage.org/image/4hct8rd01/) what I want to achieve. What I have so far is [this](http://postimage.org/image/nsi56nv25/).
My main window is deriving from a wxFrame. I split the window using wxSplitterWindow into two windows : the one on the left - a wxTreeCtrl and the one on the right is a wxPanel. My question is how to achieve the following: a horizontal list (perhaps a grid?) that shows like records from a db, but with a scroll, so that only like 20-30 are shown, and a simple textarea below this table(grid?).

I tried to split the wxPanel, just like I did with the Frame, but it doesn't work. When I tried to change the Panel to a Frame it worked, but the Frame is opened in a new window. So now I'm asking what elements to use and how to position them so that I have a scrollable table, a horizontal line, and then a simple textarea. The horizontal line should be in the middle of the left panel. Here's my code for the right panel so far:
package RightPanel;

```
use strict;

use base qw(Wx::Panel);
use Wx qw(:everything);
sub new {
    my ($class, $parent_window) = @_;
my ($self) = $class->SUPER::new($parent_window);

    return $self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `wxSplitterWindow` is intended for a window that can be split and unsplit at run time. Text editors often have this sort of feature so that they can offer two independent views of the same document.

I assume you will always want three independent windows in your frame? You should simply create the three windows separately and do the arithmetic to align them. It sounds like you want a `wxScrolledWindow` at the top and a `wxPanel` at the bottom.

Comment: But in what control should I put the wxScrolledWindow and the wxPanel?

Comment: @MilanMilanov: Make all three windows children of the `wxFrame`. You don't have to fill it with a single window.

Answer (score 0):

Create a BoxSizer with wxHORIZONTAL flag for the window.

In this BoxSizer, create a Panel (your left-side area) and another BoxSizer -- with wxVERTICAL flag -- as your right-side area. (the above wxHORIZONTAL flag will put these two side-by-side).

In the right-side BoxSizer, create a ScrolledWindow (top part) and a Panel (bottom part).  The wxVERTICAL flag in the right-side BoxSizer will stack these on vertically.

Sizers are tricky to get your head around if you've never played with them before... this might help:
  [Sizers and Layout](http://www.wxperl.it/p/sizers-and-layout.html)